# File path encoding

Tags: java, file, character-encoding, decode

Can you help me to get the correct file path? I give in the arguments a link to a file with the name:

> GovHK 香港政府一站通：Homepage (Residents).webloc

And instead of it I receive:

> GovHK ???????:Homepage (Residents).webloc

So I can not get file, `file.exists();` returns `false`

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        if (args.length > 0) {
            File file = new File(args[0]);
            System.out.println("Exists: " + file.exists());
        }
    }
}
```

File was taken from MacOS to Windows.

You can see the original file [here](https://github.com/benchdoos/benchdoos.github.io/raw/master/GovHK%20%E9%A6%99%E6%B8%AF%E6%94%BF%E5%BA%9C%E4%B8%80%E7%AB%99%E9%80%9A%EF%BC%9AHomepage%20(Residents).webloc)

How can I get the real file path to handle it?
Thank you!

**UPD**

If I get list of files in the directory, file path is showing correctly and files exist. So the problem is on way `cmd -> jar`

Comment: I assume you're not using the right code page. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388490/unicode-characters-in-windows-command-line-how).

Comment: @CedricKring That did not help, I've tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @MikitaBerazouski [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46082954/how-to-pass-hieroglyphs-as-an-argument-to-the-main-method-from-command-line), we found out that it is an issue of Windows console encoding.

[UPDATE]

[Used JNI to get real command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70573213/2396497)